# How to create different development and production configurations for devise gem in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

How to create different development and production configurations for devise gem in rails 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit the `config/environments/development.rb` and `config/environments/production.rb` to specify development and production configurations, respectively.